# VM "Mapper" partition resize to full extend

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I just resized my Ubuntu VM (under proxmox) from 32GB to 100GB. However this did not have the efect I was hoping for. It seems the space is there but is not allocated to /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv nor to /dev/sda3.

How can I make sure my mapper partition will use all the free space ?

fdisk -l here: https://pastebin.com/dnn7cBzi

Comment: You need to increase the partition size, logical volume and filesystem.

Comment: Extend the partition from within the OS

Comment: I understand this, but how do I do it ? Any good step by step how to ? 
All I found on internet was rather cryptic and I dont want to risk experimenting with confusing how-to's :(